# Create an array of objects from another array of objects and add more properties to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects and want to add come extra properties to the object and get the new array of objects

```
const notificationList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    primary: 'Item1',
    secondary: 'Desc1',
    date: 'Jan 2, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    primary: 'Item2',
    secondary: 'Desc2',
    date: 'Jan 10, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    primary: 'Item3',
    secondary: 'Desc3',
    date: 'Dec 9, 2018'
  },
];
```

And I need to get the below list

```
const notificationNewList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    icon: <Icon1 />,
    color: 'error',
    primary: 'Item1',
    secondary: 'Desc1',
    date: 'Jan 2, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    icon: <Icon2 />,
    color: 'primary',
    primary: 'Item2',
    secondary: 'Desc2',
    date: 'Jan 10, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    icon: <Icon3 />,
    color: 'secondary',
    primary: 'Item3',
    secondary: 'Desc3',
    date: 'Dec 9, 2018'
  },
];

const notificationsNewList = notificationList && notificationList.map(data => {
      data.icon = (data.id === '1' ? <Icon1 /> : (data.id === '2' ? <Icon2 /> : <Icon3 />));
      data.color = (data.id === '1' ? 'error' : (data.id === '2' ? 'primary' : 'secondary'));
    })
```

But this does not seem to work. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to return `data` in your `map()` callback. You should also copy `data` if you don't want to add properties to the original objects.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the map function. Try something like  `.map( data => ({ ...data, icon : /*...*/, color: /*...*/ }) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `...` *spread* or `Object.assign`

```js
function getIconJSX(data) => (data.id == 1 && <Icon1/>) || (data.id == 2 && <Icon2/>) || (data.id == 3 && <Icon3/>)

const notificationList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    primary: 'Item1',
    secondary: 'Desc1',
    date: 'Jan 2, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    primary: 'Item2',
    secondary: 'Desc2',
    date: 'Jan 10, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    primary: 'Item3',
    secondary: 'Desc3',
    date: 'Dec 9, 2018'
  },
];

const newNotificationList = notificationList.map(x => ({...x, Icon: getIconJSX(x)}))

console.log(newNotificationList)
```